# Find the top 10 most frequent 2 word sequences in a text using bash

Tags: bash, unix

I use `cat test.txt | grep -o -E '\w+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10` to find the top 10 repeated words, but could you help me to find top 10 repeated 2 word sequences?

Comment: Perhaps replacing `'\w+'` with `'\w \w'` would server your purpose?

Comment: Please, post some sampe text with related expected output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the help.. replacing '\w+' with '\w+ \w+' solves it.

Comment: How did replacing word `\w+` to single character that is `w` character helped you?

Is file splited into pairs?

Comment: @VineetD glad it helped. `'\w+'` (is **one** or more occurrences of a word), you needed `'\w \w'` to insure you matches **two** occurrences of a word.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `cat` program.  `grep`, and other *filter programs* take a filename as their rightmost argument.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As @AlexBaranowski mentioned  `'\w \w'` is implying two occurrences of single characters.

Comment: @cdarke thanks for the update.

Comment: It implies **two** *character classes* of `[:word:]` which is an alphanumeric sequence of characters. If you have two one-character words back to back, like `"I a"`, then it could match two one-character words.

Comment: I am not sure but the script just outputs the last character and first character of the words if `\w \w` is being used.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : I think your approach would fail for the input text  `A X Y B C X Y B D X Y Z` . It would count the word groups A X, Y B, C X, Y B, D X, and Y Z, yielding Y B as the most frequent pair, while the most frequent one is X Y (3 occurances).

Comment: @user1934428 if you want to ask that question, you may be right. However, I can only go by what the person who wrote this question reports.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Maybe a misunderstanding of my side, but I initially interpreted the question in the way that he wanted to look at any consecutive words; hence my answer. But now when I look at it, I see (was it always there, or was the question edited after I posted my comment?) that he wants to count *only repeated* words. This means that in the text `A B C X X D Y Y E F X X`, only X X and Y X are significant and everything else is treated as noise. In this case, both of our approaches wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one for GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="[,.]? "                           # add more punctuations
}
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++)                     # loop all words in record
        a[tolower($i OFS $(i+1))]++       # store word pairs and increase count
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" # set the for traverse order 
    for(i in a) {                         # loop pairs
        print i,a[i]                      # print pair and count
        if(++j==10)                       # after top-10
            exit                          # guess
    }
}' lorem_ipsum.txt                        # some text
```

Output:

```
sit amet 6
ac ultricies 2
tellus donec 2
sed odio 2
sagittis quis 2
est duis 2
vitae luctus 2
donec eu 2
nec tincidunt 2
nullam nec 2
```

And if "this other" = "other this" replace `a[tolower($i OFS $(i+1))]++` with 
`a[tolower(($i<$(i+1)?$i OFS $(i+1):$(i+1) OFS $i))]++`.